# Yocto Linux, root logging error : libcrypt does not support MD5 or SHA512

Tags: yocto

I'm building Linux image using yocto 4.2. I've already set up the root password on the `local.conf` file with hash generated my MD5 using openssl `openssl passwd -1 root`

```
INHERIT += "extrausers"
EXTRA_USERS_PARAMS = "usermod -p '\$1$bI3FOrM/$aAr4Ar09j0BXowgMygJWt0' root;"
```

I'm getting the following error when trying to login as root.

```
root logging error crypt method not supported by libcrypt? (MD5)
```

Then I tried `SHA256` or `SHA512` hash using `openssl passwd -6 root` and getting the same error !!

```
qemuarm64 login: root
    Password: 
    crypt method not supported by libcrypt? (SHA512)
```

Comment: md5 is not a sensible password hash in 2023. It's really really broken. Not having it in libcrypt is the right choice. The `man 5 crypt` manpage has been telling people this for decades, so I force myself to have no compassion here :) You're a fine person nevertheless, probably! You also probably want to use libxcrypt instead of libcrypt, if you want to use sha512crypt. Otherwise, yescrypt.

Comment: but how to use libxcrypt or yescrypt instead of libcrypt with Yocto?

Comment: Use `usermod -P plainTextPassword root;` and yocto will select the encryption method by itself (not sure which one this will be for 4.2) and include the required library.

Comment: nop, not working with plain text password. I get error `core-image-full-cmdline: usermod command did not succeed.` Plaintext is no longer supported as mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/a/75367969/4838002